# Why is this jquery easing sample not working in JSFiddle?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I am putting together a menu based on this: http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/how-to-make-a-smooth-animated-menu-with-jquery/

It works on my local machine, but when I put it in JSFiddle the easing doesn't work.

The code that isn't working is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 //When mouse rolls over
 $("li").mouseover(function () {
     $(this).stop().animate({
         height: '150px'
     }, {
         queue: false,
         duration: 600,
         easing: 'easeOutBounce'
     });
 });

 //When mouse is removed
 $("li").mouseout(function () {
     $(this).stop().animate({
         height: '50px'
     }, {
         queue: false,
         duration: 600,
         easing: 'easeOutBounce'
     });
 });

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/EyFPB/1/

What have I missed? I added the easing plugin, and as far as I can see JQuery is there too.

Sure it's something silly I missed...

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with leeching and the message "Please stop hotlinking my easing script — use a real CDN instead. Many thanks"

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually linked to the easing plugin... If you actually *go* to the easing script, you'll see that it only contains the message not to hotlink it.

```
/* 
 * Please note: 
 * This is not the easing plugin, for that you need to go to 
 * http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js 
 * Many thanks,
 * George
 */
```

This made big news on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6106757) not too long ago.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me using the same code and the cdn http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/EyFPB/6/ -- Link is `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js`

Comment: So - is the menu sliding out for you? I don't see this. :-(

Comment: Sorry - tried in another browser and it worked. Maybe a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

The message displayed makes it pretty clear.  The script you are linking does not allow you to hotlink.  That means you need to download the easing js file and host it yourself.

Comment: Please try again - this is going to the correct link, but same issue. (Also, if I try just doing an alert on mouseover I get the same issue.)

Comment: Also - do you know if it is possible to add the .js file to JSFiddle rather than hotlinking? Couldn't work out how to do this

Comment: Or use a CDN, like [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js)